# Is there any DS2482 I2C to 1-Wire bridge functional library?

Tags: i2c, 1-wire

Please let me know if you know any good library for DS2482 I2C to 1-Wire bridge.
I tried to use [the DS2482_OneWire library](https://github.com/cybergibbons/DS2482_OneWire)  but I got errors when trying to run the library examples (**Read_temp_sensors** and **Scan_1Wire_Bus**):

Error for Read_temp_sensors:

> Read_temp_sensors:2:10: fatal error: DallasTemperature.h: No such file or directory

Error for Scan_1Wire_Bus:

> Scan_1Wire_Bus 
> C:\Users\myuser\Documents\Arduino\libraries\DS2482_OneWire-master\OneWire.cpp: In member function 'uint8_t OneWire::waitOnBusy()':
> C:\Users\myuser\Documents\Arduino\libraries\DS2482_OneWire-master\OneWire.cpp:121:3: error: 'delayMicroseconds' was not declared in this scope
> delayMicroseconds(20);
> ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
> exit status 1 Error compiling for board Arduino Nano.**

Thank you.

Comment: Please take a look at this library, https://github.com/mikaelpatel/Arduino-OWI. It handles both DS2482 and GPIO implementation. https://github.com/mikaelpatel/Arduino-OWI/blob/master/examples/DS2482/DS18B20/DS18B20.ino

Comment: The documentation may be found here, https://mikaelpatel.github.io/Arduino-OWI/dc/dfe/Hardware_2OWI_8h.html and https://mikaelpatel.github.io/Arduino-TWI/d4/d53/classDS2482.html

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I guess to solve the first error, you also need [this library](https://github.com/milesburton/Arduino-Temperature-Control-Library), which contains the DallasTemperature.h file. The file get's included, but is not contained in the DS2482 library. Unfortunately there is no clue for that in the readme of the library. The author didn't commit anything since 2014, so the development of the library can be considered dead from that side. Though some people have forked the library to make little changes.

And the solution to the second error is described in [this issue](https://github.com/cybergibbons/DS2482_OneWire/issues/3) of the DS2482 library (just adding an include of "Arduino.h" in the OneWire.cpp file).

Comment: Hello @chrisl, Thank you for your prompt answer. I don't know how to implement it: "// Constructor with no parameters for compatability with OneWire lib
OneWire::OneWire()"... ecc " I still get an error for the second issue: bool isAllZeros(const uint8_t* const scratchPad, const size_t length = 9);

       ^~~~~~~~~~   Maybe you can still help me...

Comment: Please include your current code into your question, then I can test this myself

Comment: Hello @chrisl. Thank's again for your time. Firstly I just want to run the examples included in the library. So the last error presented before was associated with Scan_1Wire_Bus.  Please let me know if you are able to run all the ex file. Thank you

Comment: I dowloaded the DS2482 library and also the Arduino-Temperature-Control library, as described in my answer. After adding `include "Arduino.h" to the top of OneWire.cpp I could successfully compile the example sketch `Scan_1Wire_Bus.ino` from the DS2482 library for the Arduino Nano. I use Arduino IDE 1.8.9

Comment: Hello @chrisl.Unfortunately,for me is still not working.If I install only 2 libraries that you recommend before I'm getting errors when I'm using #include <DallasTemperature.h>.If I install the OneWire library directly from Manage Library I will not receive errors for the inclusion of "DallasTemperature.h": but I'm getting new errors I think because both libraries (DS2482/OneWire) has the same name "OneWire ".Because of this the object defineded in DS2482 are not visible anymore (class OneWire'has no member named 'checkPresence') Please let me know if I'm doing something wrong now . Thank you

Comment: Then you have 2 options: You can delete the OneWire library and only keep the DS2482 one. Or you can rename the DS2482 OneWire class to a different name. For the second option you would need to rename it both in OneWire.h and OneWire.cpp